# How can native-debug-symbols be used with ndk-stack?

Tags: android, symbolicatecrash, ndk-stack

Using ndk-stack with the libraries, generated in ./build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/arm64-v8a/ for example, I am able to get debug information, including line numbers. However gradle 4.1.0 and above has the option to generate native-debug-symbols via the configuration **debugSymbolLevel 'full'**. Supposedly the Play Store has the ability to use those symbols to symbolicate crash traces but ndk-stack only seems to accept .so files whereas the native-debug-symbols are .so.dbg files.

I tried merging the stripped binaries with the .so.dbg symbol files using eu-unstrip, for example, but that's not part of the ndk and the resulting files did not result in the crash getting symbolicated. I tried other stuff as well but nothing worked.

What is the proper way to symbolicate crashes locally via the native-debug-symbols?

Answer (score 0):

H!

I managed:

1. rename *.so.dbg to *.so
2. use ndk-stack

It works!

Comment: Please include some explanations.